# Jquery DatetimePicker desired format is lost. The 'seconds' part is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datetimepicker, datetime-format

Context: Helping out a co-worder fix a bug. He also did not write this code. Current code is a merge of 2 developers code. Both are not available any more.

Initially the date time picker loads and shows a correct format:

[image: Good situation]

But then once you select a different time, it removes the '**seconds**' part from the value.

[image]

The problem only occurs when jquery.validate is added to the index.cshtml page.
Otherwise the original format is respected.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Which refers to:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

This is the actual control:

```
<input type="text" id="snapshotDateTime" class="form-control datetimepicker">
```

And this is the datetimepicker initialization:

```
function initializeDateTimePicker(datetime) {

    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        format: 'd-m-Y H:i:s',
        formatTime: 'H:i',
        formatDate: 'd-m-Y',
        lang: 'nl',
    });

    // Initial datetime at startup
    if (datetime == null) {
        $("#snapshotDateTime").val(getFormattedDateTime(new Date()));
    }
    else {
        $("#snapshotDateTime").val(getFormattedDateTime(datetime));
    }
}
```

**Now my question is**: How to fix this issue, so that jquery validate can be used and not lose the **seconds**.

(I would also appreciate hints, as where to look for a potential solution.)

*Disclaimer: I am not a javascript specialist.*

Maybe not relevant, but this is the implementation of ***getFormattedDateTime***

```
function getFormattedDateTime(d) {

    try {
        var dateTimeString = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
            d.getFullYear() + " " + ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
        return dateTimeString;
    }
    catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the jQuery validate configuration that gets applied?

Comment: What should I look for? How does jQuery validate configuration typically look like?

Comment: Should have a `.validate()` call somewhere in the JS, and presumably it will also get passed some options. https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: It appears a template is being used, you pointed me in the correct direction. I will look further from here. And update this question with my findings. Thanx so far.

Comment: Ok. I am able to fix the datetimepicker by changing the format of the .datetimepicker call in the layout. (template) But now I have introduced a new problem. All datetimepickers on the page now show seconds. I only want this one to show seconds.

Comment: Even when I select the specific element:             $('#snapshotDateTime').datetimepicker({
                format: 'd-m-Y H:i:s',
                lang: 'nl',
            });  it still changes ALL the datetimepickers format.

Comment: Try and initialize that particular one using `$('#snapshotDateTime').datetimepicker()`, and the rest using `$('.datetimepicker:not(#snapshotDateTime)').datetimepicker()`

Comment: You gave me the right answer. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to @Cbroe the solution was found:

```
        $('.datetimepicker:not(#snapshotDateTime)').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd-m-Y H:i',
            lang: 'nl',
        });
        $('#snapshotDateTime').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd-m-Y H:i:s',
            lang: 'nl',
        });
```